# Web pack setup to include flag-icon-css

Tags: javascript, css, webpack

I am setting a webpack project using https://github.com/teroauralinna/webpack-guide, initial set up working fine. Now, I want to include https://github.com/lipis/flag-icon-css in my project. So I followed the below steps:

```
npm install flag-icon-css --save
```

and dev dependencies created in my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "flag-icon-css": "^3.3.0"
  },
```

Now in my index.html file, I have given

```
<h1> Samples </h1>
<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-gr"></span>
<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-gr flag-icon-squared"></span>
```

But only `Samples` text is visible but the other two icons are not visible. Are there any other settings I need to give for the icons to appear?

Comment: you need to call the file. installed but not called. so it might be like `import flag-icon from 'flag-icon-css'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `app.js` file adding the below has solved the issue:

```
import 'flag-icon-css/css/flag-icon.css'
```

Comment: I use Vue and had to add `import 'flag-icon-css/css/flag-icons.css'` to the main.js. In my case it had to be `.../flag-icons.css` with an s at the end.

Answer (score 0):

In your `nuxt.config.js` file, you can set the CSS file directly :

```
  css: [
    // .... others css files
    '../node_modules/flag-icon-css/css/flag-icon.css'
  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar case as @Madasu-k, *(my case, in laravel)*, when adding the following code into `app.scss` (as per some documentation im following):

```
// Flag Icon CSS
@import '~flag-icon-css/sass/flag-icon';
```

i noticed that the laravel mix fails as it tries to look for the file `flag-icon.scss`.

Checking into the folder "node_moduels", the actual file `flag-icon` contains an 's'.

Hence, the following update should be:

```
// Flag Icon CSS
@import '~flag-icon-css/sass/flag-icons';
```

Running the laravel mix / loading the webpack solved my issue.